# Probability of nearest neighbor point

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

Given a set of $n$ points uniformly distributed in a disk $R$ of radius $r$, consider one of the chosen points located at $x \in R$. What is the probability that $x$ is the closest chosen point to another point located at $y \in R$?

Comment: If $r$ is sufficiently large so that the disc with radius $|x-y|$ and with center at $y$ is completely inside $R$, then this is the probability that all the other points are outside this disc: 
$$\left(1-\frac{|x-y|^2}{r^2}\right)^{n-2}$$
If $r$ is not so large, you need to calculate the area of intersection of $R$ and  the smaller disc.

Comment: Is the point $x$ supposed to be chosen uniformly at random? In other words do you mean, what is the probability a random point is the nearest neighbour to some other point?

Comment: Suppose one of the $n$ points chosen uniformly at random inside the disk happens to be located at $x$. Now we consider another point (not among the $n$ chosen points) at $y$. What is the probability that the closest chosen point to $y$ is the point at $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've required that $y$ is not amongst the chosen points, NCh's comment is slightly off. Let $B(p,\hat{r})$ be the disk of radius $\hat{r}$ centered at some point $p$ (e.g., note $R=B(0,r)$), then
$$\left(1 - \frac{V\big(B(y, \|x-y\|_2) \cap B(0,r)\big)}{\pi r^2}\right)^{n-1}$$
where $V(\cdot)$ denotes area.

More generally, in $\mathbb{R}^d$,
$$\left(1 - \frac{\Gamma(n/2 + 1)\cdot V\big(B(y, \|x-y\|_2) \cap B(0,r)\big)}{\pi^{d/2} r^d}\right)^{n-1}$$
where $V(\cdot)$ denotes the $d$-hypervolume.